# Does the Polish parliament keep a compendium of its votes?

Tags: parliament, poland, voting-records

I'm looking for a website or a similar resource that could serve as a hub for records of all votes the [Parliament of Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliament_of_Poland) has undertaken, at least for the past year but preferably more comprehensive. I'd prefer an English-language resource, but I'd settle for Polish.

Comment: Context: trying to answer http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36304/has-jesus-been-declared-the-king-of-poland/36309?noredirect=1#comment139441_36309

Comment: @user4012 Hopefully it has wider applicability as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your prayers can be answered. Nice data visualizations too.  See [Data mining the Polish Parliament](https://dzone.com/articles/data-mining-of-the-votes-of-members-of-parliament) although it will be helpful if you have some data background.

> 7th term of the Sejm has already come to its end. It would be nice to see how have the Members of Polish Parliament voted for these last 4 years! In total they took part in over 6000 votings. Did the representatives of the same clubs voted more similarly to each other? Did the Members of Polish Parliament who changed the clubs they belonged to voted in a different way than the Members of Parliament from their former clubs? Let’s see!
>
> Data on votings may be found in the package called sejmRP: https://github.com/mi2-warsaw/sejmRP.

Comment: It might be good to comment on who actually offers the voting data. The question is how trustworthy it is? Is it official? A respectable organization? Some individuals?

Answer (score 2):

Official records published by parliament for current term.

http://www.sejm.gov.pl/sejm8.nsf/agent.xsp?symbol=posglos&NrKadencji=8

For previous term.

http://www.sejm.gov.pl/sejm8.nsf/agent.xsp?symbol=posglos&NrKadencji=7